# Where to Download Brain Anatomy 3D Model?

Tags: brain, anatomy, technology, endoscopy, medical-training

I am doing a virtual reality simulation for endoscopic brain surgery. I need a medically accurate 3D model of a human head. It has to include all the veins, skull, muscles, nerves and brain  anatomy.  This simulation will be used to train students on the surgery. Where do I buy downloadable full anatomy 3D models?

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. Not only are we not a shopping advice site, for [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: People could advise you on where to go, but then you could find that the advice doesn't provide exactly what you need.

Comment: By "medically accurate", are you including a range of natural variability in e.g. sizes and locations of features?